# Modal Popup wont popup unless page is checked out?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, modal-dialog, jquery-ui

I have a strange situation whereby I have written my own code to open a modal popup window as shown below:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function showInPopup(popupURL)
{
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions(); 
     options.url = popupURL;
     options.width = 700;
     options.height = 540;
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
</script>
```

For some reason this only works when I have the page (which includes this JS) checked out or me via the SP UI. When i do this the popup works for me and everyone else on the site. Once i check it in it no longer works...anyone ever seen this?

Regards,

S

Comment: Where do you add this script? It is not in an EditModePanel or smoething, right?

Comment: The script was added in the Snippit webpart...

Comment: What is a snippit webpart? But ok. Have you checked the console for error messages? is SP.UI loaded?

Comment: Its a webpart that allows you to add embeded code like JS etc. the SP.UI JS file is built into SP and is available in the _layout folder

Comment: I know it is built in to SharePoint, but is it loaded on your page? :)

Comment: yes when i view source the SP.UI.Dialog.js is referenced...

Comment: OK, I would guess the error lies in your "Snippit" webpart then

Comment: Find it strange that when checked out it works though...

Comment: True that, have you tried just adding the script to a ContentEditorWebpart html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally worked it out, turns out the Masterpage that SP2013 created from my HTML page did NOT include the required JS files for modal popups to work. I had to edit the HTML file in SPD2013 and add the following code.

```
<!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink2" Name="SP.js" runat="server"     OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false">-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink3" Name="SP.UI.Dialog.js" runat="server" OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false">-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink4" Name="SP.Ribbon.js" runat="server" OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false">-->
```

I would have thought that this would have been added when the Masterpage was created/converted. One to watch out for.

Cheers for the input.

S

Comment: Haha, so I was right about the the SP.Ui not being loaded? :P

Comment: Yes! ;-) I stupidly thought that the code to add the SP.UI JS files were added during the conversion process of HTML to Master page. Thanks for the help!